# Passing URL query strings into HTML form fields using Javascript

Tags: javascript, php, html, forms, static-site

I have always used PHP for passing query strings into forms, but I am looking to move to a static site scenario and need the query data from a URL to populate the form fields.

I have the code with no console errors, but the data is not passing into the form fields. Does anyone know how this can be done that works across all modern and legacy browsers?

```
function getQueryString() {
    var result = {};
    if(!window.location.search.length) return result;
    var qs = window.location.search.slice(1);
    var parts = qs.split("&");
    for(var i=0, len=parts.length; i<len; i++) {
        var tokens = parts[i].split("=");
        result[tokens[0]] = decodeURIComponent(tokens[1]);
    }
    return result;
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#theForm").submit(function(e) {
        //var that = this;
        var qs = getQueryString();
        for(var key in qs) {
            var field = $(document.createElement("input"));
            field.attr("name", key).attr("type","hidden");
            field.val(qs[key]);
            $(this).append(field);
        }
    });
});
```

https://formpopulate.netlify.com/index.html?name=john&email=john@aol.com
https://formpopulate.netlify.com/

Comment: When you mean `URL query strings`, do you mean you're sending your form using GET methods?

Comment: What have you tried? It's an easy search to find code to parse the url search params to an object. From there it's fairly easy to match fields to params

Comment: Code shown is working on submit in your page. Can run `$('#theForm').submit(e=>e.preventDefault())` in console then click submit button and see the hidden inputs and values

Comment: But note that you are duplicating `name` in example. The hidden fields have same names as the visible ones

Comment: be careful with `&field[]` type of fields.

Comment: This URL provides the easiest and best solution https://lightignite.com/help-your-customers-fill-out-web-forms-with-url-query-strings/

Answer (score 0):

You should use URL seachParams:

```js
var params = (new URL("https://example.com/?name=Jonathan&age=18&test=a%20long%20string")).searchParams;
var name = params.get("name"); console.log(name); // is the string "Jonathan"
var age = parseInt(params.get("age")); console.log(age);// is the number 18
var test = params.get("test"); console.log(test); // is a long string
```